# 'std::bad_weak_ptr' error while using shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, enable-shared-from-this

Note: Before posting the question, I have gone through the existing questions on `std::bad_weak_error` while using `shared_from_this` to pass the shared_ptr of the existing `shared_ptr` instance to another method. None of them are similar to this as:

- There is already an existing shared_ptr instance of the class created before trying to call `shared_from_this()`
- The class inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>` publically.

Here is the sample code to reproduce the error:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class ILogger {
public:
    virtual ~ILogger() {}

    virtual void Log() = 0;
};

class LogManager;

class Logger : public ILogger {
public:
    Logger(std::shared_ptr<LogManager> logManager)
        : m_logManager(logManager)
    {
    }

    void Log() override
    {
        std::cout << "Dump logs";
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<LogManager> m_logManager;
};

class ILogManager {
public:
    virtual ~ILogManager() {}

    virtual std::shared_ptr<ILogger> GetLogger() = 0;
};

class LogManager : public ILogManager, public std::enable_shared_from_this<LogManager> {
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<ILogger> GetLogger()
    {
        return std::static_pointer_cast<ILogger>(std::make_shared<Logger>(this->shared_from_this()));
    }
};

class LogManagerFactory {
public:
    static ILogManager* Create()
    {
        auto logManager = new LogManager();
        return logManager;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto logManager = std::shared_ptr<ILogManager>(LogManagerFactory::Create());
    auto logger = logManager->GetLogger();
}
```

The error:

```
Program returned: 139
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

Link to code: https://godbolt.org/z/GTcafM449

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the `enable_shared_from_this` subobject to be initialized, the `shared_ptr` constructor needs to know that the class in question inherits from `enable_shared_from_this`. Look at the expression that creates the shared pointer:

> `std::shared_ptr<ILogManager>(LogManagerFactory::Create());`

The only class involved in this expression does **not** inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<>`. You are creating a shared pointer to `ILogManager` from a pointer to `ILogManager`. This is what the compiler generates code for – creating a `shared_ptr` for a class that does not inherit from `enable_shared_from_this`. The constructor is not aware that you are expecting it to initialize an `enable_shared_from_this` subobject.

The code works if you change the return type of `LogManagerFactory::Create()` from `ILogManager*` to `LogManager*`. You can keep the `std::shared_ptr<ILogManager>` part as long as the construction parameter brings `LogManager` into the picture.

***Note:** To be safer, `LogManagerFactory::Create()` should return either a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` instead of a raw pointer to clearly communicate that the caller gains ownership.*

Answer (score 3):

When you run:

```
std::shared_ptr<ILogManager>(LogManagerFactory::Create())
```

`shared_ptr` only knows the pointer is an `ILogManager` which doesn't have `enable_shared_from_this` so doesn't set the weak pointer.

The solution (and safer code in general) is to create the `shared_ptr` in `Create` at which point the constructor can see the true type and `enable_shared_from_this` will therefore work:

```
    static std::shared_ptr<ILogManager> Create()
    {
        auto logManager = new LogManager();
        return std::shared_ptr<ILogManager>(logManager);
    }
```

Or more simply:

```
    static std::shared_ptr<ILogManager> Create()
    {
        return std::make_shared<LogManager>();
    }
```